How to remote control a wayland program with ssh similar to DISPLAY=:0 under X11?
I'm running a laptop and a HTPC with Kubuntu Oracular 24.10. Before, they were running older releases under X11, now I have switched to Wayland with the new release.
My issue: For years, I have used the laptop as a remote control to start videos on a big TV screen under X11 on the HTPC.
Typically, it looked like this:
<local>  $ ssh remote.lan
<remote> $ DISPLAY=:0 mpv /location/of/video/file
...

Unfortunately, there is no DISPLAY=:0 in Wayland.
When I try to run mpv /location/of/video/file via ssh, I only get an error:
        vd: Using hardware decoding (nvdec-copy).
   cplayer: AO: [pipewire] 44100Hz stereo 2ch floatp
   cplayer: VO: [gpu-next] 1280x720 nv12
vo/gpu-next/libplacebo: vk->CreateSwapchainKHR(...): VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN (../src/vulkan/swapchain.c:620)
vo/gpu-next/libplacebo: Failed (re)creating swapchain!
               cplayer: Could not initialize video chain.
               cplayer: Video: no video

and the player just plays the audio from the file.
(Maybe) relevant parts from mpv.conf:
###### Vulkan Linux, Windows (preferred)
gpu-api=vulkan
...
hwdec=nvdec-copy                                # enable hardware decoding, defaults to 'no'
vo=gpu-next                             # GPU-Next: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/GPU-Next-vs-GPU
...

How can I restore the old X11 behaviour under Wayland?
I want to remote control via ssh a program on a remote PC which has AV output on the remote side, so anything like waypipe doesn't fit here.
And I don't want to switch back to X11 when everybody moves to Wayland.
